# Image is a subset of the preimage

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be an infinite set and $f:A\to A$ a function. Show that there is a nonemtpy subset $B\subset A$ such that $f[B]\subseteq B$.
I would like a hint on how to approach this.

Comment: $B\subset A$ not $B\subseteq A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $B$ has to be nonempty, I'd start by picking a random element $x\in A$ and putting it in $B$. If we want $f[B]\subseteq B$, then if $x\in B$ we also have to have $f(x)\in B$, and $f(f(x))\in B$, and so on.

So let's try $B=\{x,f(x),f(f(x)),\dots\}$. Does that work? For sure $f[B]\subseteq B$, and $B$ is nonempty. If $B\neq A$ we're done! Well, what if $B=A$? Are the elements $x,f(x),f(f(x)),\dots$ all different? What happens if we start with $f(x)$, and take $B=\{f(x),f(f(x)),\dots\}$?